# Could not be able to change passwords

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using ASP.NET MVC5 and I wanted to change password of an account but I keep getting errors saying "validation failed for one or more entities. See the validation error" and the source code error is

```
var result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.oldPassword, model.NewPassword);
```

Comment: See the validation error"  where???? @ILoveCode

Comment: on the code I've posted. my password matches and passes all the requirement

Comment: @ShakirAhamed need your help

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your `ChangePasswordAsync` where I assume you are saving the changes to the password i.e. to the entity containing the password. In order to give you more precise answer I'd need your logic for this method.

My guess would be that either your entity wasn't found and the EF tries to save the changes to the new entity and since the new entity has no values for the property that's the reason for getting the error or that the found entity is missing some values.

Check this nifty little snippet that could help you debug and find out on which property does the error occur. Note: **Entities** is a partial class of your Entities class so change the name accordingly.

```
public partial class Entities
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                    .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                    .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

            var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

            var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

            throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
        }
    }
}
```